# HP EliteBook 840 G9 - i5-1235u vs i7-1255u

Tags: laptop

I am in a process of buying a new laptop, in this case an update to my HP EliteBook G5 i7 that have been great, super quiet and good performance.

Now I am looking to the new G9 but I don't know which one to choose, the i5-1235u or i7-1255u.

When I search for performance results, I find 13814 for the i5 and 13107 for the i7 (https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare/Intel-i5-1235U-vs-Intel-i7-1255U/4765vs4794)

My main goal are quiet because I dont need performance in a daily basis, but I would appreciate your help on this.

Thank You.

Comment: Don't look at random benchmark scores

Comment: Hi thanks, what would be your advice to make a choice?

Comment: Look at reviews, ask your local computer shop, or buy a Framework laptop

Comment: but not random benchmark scores that may not ever really reflect your use case

Comment: It's a brand new model, there are no reviews yet unfortunatly.

Comment: Then there should be two options left I can reccomend, ask your local computer store or buy a Framework

Comment: Your local computer store probably knows your use case better so can also better estamate which laptop is best, even better than I can